# Difference in merge strategies from hoftix branches to master and develop branches

Tags: git, git-flow

Using git flow it's noted that `hotfix` branches are branched from `master` and merged back to both `master` and `develop`.

However, it's plausible that merging `hotfix` to `develop` will cause merge conflicts, which is why my team is currently advocating to merge `hotfix` into `master` and then back from `master` do `develop`.

But I think that the scenarios that will create conflicts from `hotfix` to `develop` would also yield conflicts on `merge` to `develop`, so there's no real benefit here.

Even worse, because they always resolve conflicts inside GitHub Pull Requests, if there's a conflict from `master` to `develop` they'll create a commit on `master` solving it before merging to `develop`.

After all, are these non-issues? Is merging from `hotfix` to both `master` and `develop` really that important or is the second approach equally fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two approaches are functionally the same most of the time, in practice.

```
1       # last common commit
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
v    \
2     3  # master follows left side commits, develop follows right side
|\   /|
| \  .|
|  |  |
|. |  |
v/ |  |
4  |  |  # 4 merged into master from feature branch, contains 3
|  |  |
|  v  |
|  5  |  # hotfix commit 5
| /|  |
v/ |  |
6  |  |  # 6 fixes conflicts between 3 and 5
|   \ | 
|    \v 
|     A  # A also fixes conflicts between 3 and 5
 \
  \   .
   \  |
    \ |
     \v
      B # merge master with hotfix to develop
```

So your possibilities to merge to develop in A or B are that A will contain commits (1, 2, 3, 5) and B will contain (1, 2, 3, **4**, 5, **6**). There could be anything in 4 or 6 that is not desirable on the develop branch for whatever reason, but in practice I don't see what that could be.

Assuming commit 4 comes from some change on develop (already is on develop), then it is possible that commit 5 and commit 4 have merge conflicts. In that special case, the conflict would have to be resolved in both 6 and A, whereas merging into B would allow to resolve those conflicts only once in 6. Solving conflicts twice also has the potential of solving them (slightly) differently, causing further merge conflicts in the future.

Comment: So the only difference is going to be in terms of graph topology? Anyway, in both cases I guess conflicts should be solved during merge directly instead of using the PR mechanism on GitHub.

Comment: Topology helps discussing. I added text about conflicts.